# What is the meaning of "Stir the pot" idiom?

Tags: idioms

Dear helpful folks who saved me several times. I need your help again :)

I am reading the introduction for the finance course and the author is using the expression "stir the pot" in the following context:

"My name is Aswath Damodaran and I teach corporate finance and valuation at the Stern School of Business at New York University. I describe myself as a teacher first, who also happens to love untangling the puzzles of corporate finance and valuation, and writing about my experiences. As a result, I happen to be at the intersection of three businesses, education, publishing and financial services, that are all big, inefficiently run and deserve to be disrupted. I may not have the power to change the status quo in any of these businesses, but ***I can stir the pot***, and this website is my attempt to do so."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/7/messages/204.html), it refers to the idea of letting  a number of unknown, possibly secret,   issues to become pubblic:

> Metaphorically, a lot of issues/resentments/obligations can drop out of sight when nobody mentions them. One can "stir the pot" to bring issues to the surface, sometimes with malice, but sometimes merely to create awareness and effect change.

Answer (score 0):

As he states he does not have real power. The way he says it is in preparation of him saying what he does in fact have, "I may not have"

Stirring the pot in this case is a way of saying he can cause some activity even if not a great deal. The purpose of his website is to make what difference he can even if only small.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please add references to support your answer.